# How do I use given gifts?

Tags: dragon-age-origins, dragon-age-origins-awakening

I've recently started Awakenings on Xbox360 and got Ser Pounce-a-lot. Its description says "Use: This item has a unique power", but I can't figure out how to use it. It's in the Useable Items section of my inventory, but it lacks a "Use" option. Am I supposed to get to it from somewhere else or is this some weird bug?

The same thing was going on in Origins with some gifts from the Feastday Gifts DLC.

Just to be clear, the items have been gifted to the appropriate people, in the case of Ser Pounce-a-lot, to Anders. They are *not* marked as gifts anymore.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You use them by giving them to one of your other party members.

If I remember correctly, you just go to the inventory page (ie. where you equip stuff) for the person you want to give the item to. Browse to the item, then press the button marked "give".

In Ser Pounce-a-lot's case, once you have given him to Anders, you can activate him via an icon in the radial menu while you are in combat.

Comment: I've already given them the item. It should be usable *after* that, after it is no longer marked as a gift, but I can't find out how.

Comment: In Ser Pounce-a-lot's case, are you able to find the activation icon in the radial menu while you are in combat?

Comment: Ah, yes, in Ser Pounce-a-lot's case, I can, thanks. Is that how the other gifts work as well, say, in Origins with the DLC? I don't remember seeing them in the radial menu.

Comment: IIRC, most gifts are only useful to boost your relationship. But, there are some "special" gifts (Ser Pounce-a-lot is one) which activate a cut-scene or have some other effect, as well as significantly boost your relationship with the receiver. Most don't have any use beyond that, AFAIK.